# Subversion on Mac -- unable to commit files

Tags: macos, svn, chown

I recently set up an svn server on Mac OS X.  I am able to checkout files, but not commit, with the error:

```
Error     Can't open file '/usr/local/repo/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

I understand this is an ownership issue -- however, I've tried various solutions I've found from searches such as:

```
chown -R subversion:subversion /usr/local/repo
```

But I get that subversion is an invalid argument (probably because there is no user or group on my machine with these names).  My issue is -- how do I create these users and a group so that are linked with the user names and passwords specified in my svn authentication file?

Thanks!
Andrew

Comment: Can you try adding users in Apple menu > System Preferences and click Accounts. ? I mean with the username same as owner of SVN repo?

Comment: I created the SVN repo with the account I'm logged in as.  The users who will be using the repo are not local users

Comment: After adding user subversion to group subversion and chowning it to the repo, I am still unable to commit.

Comment: sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /path/to/repo AND then 
chmod -R u+w /path/to/repo

Comment: Sadly, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this surely is a permissions problem:

As I dont know the user and the group here, so what i would suggest is using:

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /path/to/repo #now new owner would be current user and the group wold become current usergroup.

chmod -R u+w /path/to/repo
```

Comment: perhaps I'm not understanding what the user and group should actually be?  I created a subversion user in a subversion group, but these were just arbitrary names. They don't coincide with the apache authentication file.

Comment: Oh yeah, You should give permissions to apache but not to the user subversion.

Comment: open up /etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf to chekc apach's user and group. from here : http://serverfault.com/questions/152175/apache-runs-as-which-user-group-under-os-x-10-6 ,  Apache user and group are _www and _www OS X 10.6.